# (React Native) Null is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is the portion of the code React Native is having trouble rendering:

```
You input {this.state.zip}.
```

Im a beginner and I was following a tutorial in "Learning React Native" yet he code in the book is not working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class WeatherProject extends Component {
  // If you want to have a default zip code, you could add one here
  getInitialState() {
    return ({
      zip: ''
    });
  }
  // We'll pass this callback to the <TextInput>
  _handleTextChange(event) {
    // log statements are viewable in Xcode,
    // or the Chrome debug tools
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.text);

    this.setState({
      zip: event.nativeEvent.text
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          You input {this.state.zip}.
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onSubmitEditing={this._handleTextChange}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    borderWidth: 2,
    height: 40
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('WeatherProject', () => WeatherProject);
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: What does “having trouble” and “not working” mean? You're getting an error message? Post the message. If it includes a line number, tell us which line that is in your post.

Answer (score 5):

In ES6 Classes (one where you are extending `Component` rather than using `createClass`), initial states are set with `this.state = {zip: ''}` in constructor.

So it would-be

```
class WeatherProject extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      zip: ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

getInitialState is typically used with React.createClass. For defining a component as class, the following code should be in constructor:

```
getInitialState() {
    return ({
      zip: ''
    });
  }
```

constructor:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    zip: ''
  }
}
```