# React native null value checking

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how can I check this markerPosition value is null or not, I need to assign it a variable laying if its null.

```
  onSendPress() {
    const { message, markerPosition } = this.props;
    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'Message/messageSend',
      payload: { message, markerPosition }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that you are binding props correctly? i.e. your `constructor` does call `super(props)`? See [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39302400/react-native-null-is-not-an-object)

Comment: yes just it calls null and crash its very simple just an if statement is enough

Comment: so to clarify you figured it out and the answer is a simple if statement correct? If so, feel free to close this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about ensuring that the markerPosition is not null and falling back to a default value, try this then:

```
onSendPress() {
    const { message, markerPosition= "default value" } = this.props;
    // now if this.props.markerPosition is not defined
    // markerPosition holds the value "default value"

    this.props.dispatch({
      type: 'Message/messageSend',
      payload: { message, markerPosition }
    });
  }
```